Implementing nn.Bilinear Layer
Can anyone help me understand the implementation of nn.Bilinear
As per the documentation, this function implements y = x1T * A * x2
taking x1 = (100,20) , x2 = (100,30') , assuming output_features = 50. The  matrix A has dimensions of [50,20,30].
I am finding it difficult how these matrices are multiplied to get the output = [100,50]
Based on the size of x1,x2 and A matrix, the multiplication seems incompatible as per  y = x1T * A * x2 . What am I missing here?

The implementation behind the scenes calculates the bilinear product, as per documentation.
That's not to say that multiplying the tensors as they are is equivalent to the bilinear layer.
If you follow the trail of the actual calculation, you end up with a python-interface function, while the actual implementation is in the cpp, where you can see that there are reshapes and flattening of the tensors so as to ensure the output is the expected expression:
Here's an excerpt from the relevant code:
  auto size1 = input1.sym_sizes();
  output_size.insert(output_size.end(), size1.begin(), size1.end() - 1);
  output_size.push_back(weight.sym_size(0));
  auto input1_flattened = input1.reshape_symint({-1, input1.sym_size(-1)});
  auto input2_flattened = input2.reshape_symint({-1, input2.sym_size(-1)});
  Tensor output = at::_trilinear(input1_flattened, weight, input2_flattened, {1,3}, {0}, {1,2}, {2,3}).reshape_symint(output_size);
  if (bias.defined()) {
    output = output + bias;
  }

Hope that helps

The notation here is definitely confusing. The transpose notation is not clarifying.
I think the operation makes more sense in einsum notation - bn,anm,bm->ba. x1 has a multiplication/reduction along the second axis of A. x2 has a multiplication/reduction along the second axis of A.
x1 = torch.randn(2, 8)
x2 = torch.randn(2, 4)
A = torch.randn(16, 8, 4)

b1 = torch.bilinear(x1, x2, A)
b2 = torch.einsum('bn,anm,bm->ba', x1, A, x2)
assert torch.allclose(b1, b2)

You can also compute the multiplications/reductions explicitly:
b3 = (x1[:,None,:,None] * A[None] * x2[:,None,None,:]).sum(-1).sum(-1)
assert torch.allclose(b1, b3)

